# WMI ManagementOperationObserver doesn't work against remote box

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, wmi

I'm trying to figure out how to do WMI queries against a remote computer asynchronously using C# on .Net 4.5.

I'm using the ManagementObjectSearcher class, and using the Get(ManagementOperationObserver watcher) method; more or less I'm using the example from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms257344(v=vs.80).aspx

It doesn't work.

Here's what I know:

When I use wbemtest to connect to the remote computer and execute a query (SELECT * FROM Win32_Service) synchronously it works.

When I set wbemtest to be asynchronous, it also works, so it isn't a configuration issue on my workstation or my target machine, and my credentials work fine.

If I have my C# code connect to my local workstation, performing the same query asynchronously using ManagementOperationObserver also works fine.

When I change my C# code to connect to my remote target machine, it doesn't work. None of the events on the ManagementOperationObserver ever fire, and my application just sits there waiting. I've left it sit there for minutes and nothing happens.

My workstation is part of a domain, and my target remote machine is not, if that matters (since wbemtest works both sync/async I'm not sure it matters).

At this point I don't know what to try next. Does ManagementOperationObserver just not work for remote queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by default, Visual Studio 2013 sets "Prefer 32bit" to true on console applications. My workstation is 64bit; I turned this off, now my remote calls work :/

Answer (score 0):

what's your explanation that in case you are running code as 32b it doesn't work, but under 64b compilation it works fine? For it's quite scary situation.

Comment: At this point I have no idea, and I haven't had time to thoroughly investigate yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying myself to get results from async call and still have issue with it: the code get executed, but I don't see the final result. 
My code is installing a printer remotely from WMI. In the Win32_Printer, I am using

```
printer.Put(operationWatcher);
```

and in the event, setting a bool that I am monitoring.

```
   private void OperationWatcher_ObjectPut(object sender, ObjectPutEventArgs e)
    {         
        if (e.Path.ClassName == "Win32_Printer")
        {
            printerSuccessfullyPut = true;
            Console.WriteLine("should be installed"); 
        }
    }
```

The code got properly executed, but I don't get my printer installed. If I make a sync call

```
printer.Put();
```

the printer is installed. Very strange.

Wonder if the issue might have similar background as the one mentioned here (about Start method with ManagementEventWatcher)
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/09/20/asynchronous-wmi-queries-stay-away-from-them/